# Prevent email clients from creating calendar links in messages

Tags: html, email, calendar, html-email

I am sending an email messages from a PHP script and some email clients parse date strings within the message and create clickable calendar "links". One example is Airmail for OSX. I am sure there are many others that do the same. I see 2 problems with this:

- The links are shown even though they actually don't exist
- I can't style them. Actually, I don't even know if they are going to be created and where.
- Anchor CSS rules are not respected for those links and they usually end up very ugly.

My current workaround is `date('Y-&#8203;m-&#8203;d')`, but honestly this is some ugly code and I am not even sure if it works with all email clients.

I am looking for a reliable way to make sure that dates are displayed properly (meaning: the way I created them) everywhere.

Answer (score 1):

> My current workaround is date('Y-​m-​d'), but honestly
>   this is some ugly code and I am not even sure if it works with all
>   email clients.

What you have used above is `zero width space` to remove the linking on a device. I have tested the following in Litmus:

```
20/02/2018
<br><br><br>
20&zwnj;/&zwnj;02&zwnj;/&zwnj;2018
```

Here is a litmus link to show how it looks: 
https://litmus.com/checklist/emails/public/cd94368

As you said the above is ugly (but gets the job done) and you are looking for alternatives, then below are different ways to do this for different email clients.

**Fix Blue Links in Gmail**

When Gmail spots an address or phone number in an email, it automatically adds an extra style declaration, which formats any link in the email that has no inline styles attached to it, as blue:

```
.ii a[href] { color: #15c; }
```

*Option 1 (link per link basis):*

HTML:

```
<span class="contact">675 Massachusetts Ave.<br>Cambridge, MA 02139, USA</span>
```

CSS:

```
.contact a {color:#000000!important; text-decoration:underline!important;}
```

*Option 2 (All links in Gmail):*

```
u + #body a {
    color: inherit;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: inherit;
    font-family: inherit;
    font-weight: inherit;
    line-height: inherit;
}
```

[Source](https://litmus.com/blog/how-to-fix-blue-links-in-gmail)

**Fix links in iOS**

*Option 1 (using meta tag):*

```
<meta content="telephone=no" name="format-detection">
```

*Option 2:*

Use Zero width non joiner as the first tested answer above

*Option 3:*

Style it like the email text or give it another color:

```
a[href^=tel]{ color:#F00; text-decoration:none;}
```

*Option 4:*

On iOS devices an attribute is injected into the link which is detected to be an address, phone number, or dates. If you took a look at the source code of an email in Apple Mail on an iPhone, you would see something like this:

```
<a href="#" x-apple-data-detectors="true">
```

Using this attribute you can style all automatically linked text in a style declaration, inside your  block:

```
a[x-apple-data-detectors] {
    color: inherit !important;
    text-decoration: none !important;
    font-size: inherit !important;
    font-family: inherit !important;
    font-weight: inherit !important;
    line-height: inherit !important;
}
```

[Source](https://litmus.com/blog/update-banning-blue-links-on-ios-devices)

I know thats a lot to take in but all options work and its just a matter of picking the right one for your job.

Let me know if you have any questions.